# Windows form controlled by main loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How can I control windows form class in the main loop?

Can I still run my code in the main loop like a console program but use windows form to display stuff? I already done that I've got windows form application and console in one but once main calls windows form that's it, it doesn't come back to main.

Can I pass variables to windows form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

When you call `Application.Run`, the method only returns when there is no active `Form` any more. This is because `Application.Run` keeps the message loop running. It blocks the current method form returning. See it as a `while (mainFormActive)`. It will never end *unless* the main form is closed.

If you want to execute code in the mean time, set up a `Task`, a `Thread` or similar, before you start the form.

And yes, you can pass variables in, just like in any [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx).